# How to enable devtools in vue 3 with typescipt in development mode

Tags: typescript, devtools, vuejs3

I'm developing a new app in vue 3 with typescript.
I have the Vue Devtools installed in Chrome, but it refuses to recognize the app as a Vue app stating `Vue.js not detected`.
The help I find on the internet is to add `Vue.config.devtools = true;` to main.js.  However `Vue` is not available in main.ts
I also find instructions to adapt the webpack configuration, but there's no webpack in the project (that was set up by `vue-cli`.

Comment: Vue 3 is not yet supported by the Vue DevTools extension.

Comment: Version 6 beta that supports Vue 3 is now available from the chrome web store [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg?hl=en):

Answer (score 14):

Download from [here](https://headwayapp.co/vue-js-devtools-changelog/timeline-and-api-166716) or use browser install:

```
vue devtools version is v6.0.0 beta
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed to do both and more.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64310948/2487565). Install the pluging for Vue 3
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63680124/2487565). Enable devtools in config

And also, if you have both plugins for Vue 2 and Vue 3 installed, you have to disable one of them to get the Vue tab in the Developer Console working.

So, if you develop with Vue 3 right now, disable the plugin for Vue 2.

Comment: If things still don't work, restart your browser.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to answers from [Tolbxela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2487565/tolbxela) and [byungster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11538384/byungster):

I put this following command into main.ts:

`app.config.performance = true;`

instead of:

`app.config.devtools = true;`

'devtools' doesn´t exists in config anymore, its breaking typescript compiler.

Additional information: I needed restart browser and set off VueDevtools stable version.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone struggles with the same problem in 2022, for us the problem was that we were using `.env` files with various env variables, especially the  `VITE_NODE_ENV=development`.

For some reason unknown to me, if Vue Devtools detects the existence of `.env` file, it will search for a property called `NODE_ENV` without the `VITE_` prefix.

And because it did not find this key in our env file (because we prefixed it with VITE_ ) it was thinking we're in production mode.

The ultimate answer is: if you're using `.env` files, add the `NODE_ENV` key and set it to `development` and magic happens.

Answer (score 1):

check on this issue https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/1244

Maybe adding this code to "main.ts" will help.

```
const app = Vue.createApp(App)

app.config.devtools = true
```

[See Guide.](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#devtools)

Comment: This is not valid for Vue 3, which is what the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `vite` you need to add in your `vite.config.js/ts`
The following flag:

**VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS** (enable/disable devtools support in production, default: false)

```
export default defineConfig({
     __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: 'true'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this row to `main.js` file and now I can see and use the Vue devtools from the browser. This will work for Vue 3

```
app.config.performance = true;
```